# Software-center Ubuntu for libraries

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed the latest stable version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS). 
I remarked that when I search for library like "Eigen or openMp", I have no result. However, in older Ubuntu versions, I could install lot of libraries. I know that I can install them via terminal, but I prefer to find them via the software-center. Is there a trick to let the software-center find such libraries ?

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: `$ apt-cache search eigen` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eigen&searchon=names ... `$ apt-cache search openmp` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=openmp&searchon=names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some libraries receive updates to support latest ubuntu versions after a considerable period of time.What you can do is downloading the debian package from internet and install it using Ubuntu Software Manager.Visit the link below for more details.

[vitux.com/3-ways-to-install-software-from-deb-packages-in-ubuntu/](https://vitux.com/3-ways-to-install-software-from-deb-packages-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I was saying that I can find this libraries for ubuntu by using "apt-get install name_library". However, I cannot find them using the GUI software-center (named also "logitheque")

Comment: Try using the Synaptic Package Manager